# Set IsPartner flag to TRUE while uploading Partner Users using Data Loader

Tags: partner-communities

I know this might be silly question but I am trying to upload at least 500 Partner Accounts using data loader and want to enable all of them as a Partner Account. While I try to do using data loader, it gives me an error for IsPartner is not writable.

Is there a way I can mass enable them as a Partner User using Data Loader or setting this flag to true in before insert trigger and upload them? Doing this manually would be too much.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are loading Partner Account or Partner User? *I am trying to upload at least 500 Partner Accounts* -- *Is there a way I can mass enable them as a Partner User*

Comment: Yes I mean Partner Users but needs to have Partner Accounts existed before you create Partner Users, right? and enabled each account as Partner. Let me know if I am missing anything here. Thanks.

Comment: Creating Partner User is a two step process - 1. Create a Contact on a Partner Account, 2. Enable the Contact as Partner User. I assume you basically want to create and enable the Accounts as Partner during your load. Because once you have already enabled the Partner Accounts, you will still need to create the Contact and Users for Partner Users.

Comment: Yes that's correct! Once I have Partner Account created then create contacts under them and enable contacts as Partner Users.

Comment: Sure. Provided a detailed answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to load Partner Accounts and that you want to enable them during the load process, you can do so using a trigger.

> I am trying to upload at least 500 Partner Accounts using data loader and want to enable all of them as a Partner Account.

As you have figured out that the field is not writable during *insert* operations. However you can *update* the `isPartner` field on an Account. What you will need here is to write an *after insert* logic in your trigger to be able to update your accounts loaded as partner accounts.

Here's an approach, how you can do so.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert) {
    List<Account> updateList = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acct : Trigger.New){
        acct.isPartner = TRUE;
        updateList.add(acct);
    }
    update updateList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me try out this and I hope it works so I can mark your answer as best.

Comment: I ran upsert over external ids and set IsPartner to True in data loader! It worked like a charm.